# how to fix Error C2102 '&' requires l-value

Tags: c++, imgui

Im using imgui to make a internal dll file so i can inject it into a video game.Trying to fix error C2102 '&' l-value.

```
if (bWriteLog)
        {
            ImGui::LogToFile();
            bWriteLog = false;
        }

        ImGui::SetNextWindowSize(ImVec2(679.0f, 786.0f));
        ImGui::Begin(acut::ToUpper(PROGRAM_NAME).c_str(), 
&bShowWindow, ImGuiWindowFlags_NoResize | 
ImGuiWindowFlags_NoScrollbar | ImGuiWindowFlags_NoCollapse);
        ImGui::SetColorEditOptions(ImGuiColorEditFlags_NoPicker | 
ImGuiColorEditFlags_NoOptions | ImGuiColorEditFlags_NoSmallPreview | 
ImGuiColorEditFlags_NoTooltip | ImGuiColorEditFlags_NoDragDrop);

        if (ImGui::TabLabels(_profiler.gMenuTabs->Domain.iMax,
acut::StringVectorToCharPointerArray(_profiler.gMenuTabs->szItems),
_profiler.gMenuTabs->Current.iValue, NULL, false, NULL,
 NULL, false, false, NULL, NULL, & ImVec2(82.0f, 25.0f)))
        {
            bWriteLog = true;
        }
```

The error I'm receiving is "error C2102: '&' requires l-value". I'm somewhat new to programming and this is the first time doing this im trying to fix Error C2102 '&' requires l-value for using the & ImVec2(82.0f, 25.0f))) on my current project.

Comment: Your posted code doesn't have any `&`. Please post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Please share the full error message. My guess would be that `bWriteLog` is `const`, either directly or because it's a member variable and the code is inside a `const`-qualified member function. But that's just guesswork. It's impossible to say for sure without a complete but small example

Comment: `ImVec2(82.0f, 25.0f)` evaluates to a temporary object and you cannot (directly) take the address of a temporary.

Comment: https://github.com/ocornut/imgui/issues/1586

Comment: @BenVoigt indeed, in C++17 it's not even an object